# how to get matplotlib ticklabel_format: style 'scientific' to only one selected 'y' axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am ploting a figure where I have two y axis, one primary and one secondary. Now I want 'scientific' style to only primary y axis. I tried with ticklabel_format but could not figure out how to make one scientific and other keep plain. Following is the code

```
x1 =(0, 1, 2)
x2 =(0.1, 5, 7)
y1 = (1e-4, 2e-4, 3e-4)
y2 = (1000, 1200, 1500)
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(x1, y1)
ax2.plot(x2, y2)
plt.ticklabel_format(axis="y", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0))
```

[here is the resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQebG.png)

I want to plot primary y axis as scientific and secondary y as plain. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should have to do is modify the last row in the code provided to use ax1 instead of plt:

```
ax1.ticklabel_format(axis="y", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0))
plt.show()
```

Your current solution is calling `ticklabel_format()` on plt; to ensure it is applied to the correct axis you should call the method on the object you want to modify.

[image: expected image]

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ax.ticklabel_format`:

```
x =(0, 1, 2)
y1 = (1e-4, 2e-4, 3e-4)
y2 = (1000, 2000, 3000)
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(x, y1)
ax2.plot(x, y2)
ax2.ticklabel_format(axis="y", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0))  # Only ax2
...
ax1.ticklabel_format(axis="y", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0))  # Only ax1
```

[image]